# Model stretches when posing in blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, vertices

I have a problem with my model that I can't seem to fix. I looked all over the internet, but I can't find any answers.

I'm making a model for a demo and when I pose it in pose mode, some of the vertices get left behind. how can I fix this?[image]

Also I'm having this strange issue where the tail stretches when I pull on the arms. How can I fix this as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That means that a few vertices aren't weighted to any of your bones. Select your rig, go to *Pose Mode*, then select your mesh and go to *Weight Paint Mode*. Now select the bone that should be controlling those vertices and using the *Add Brush* add some weight to those vertices and they will automatically update and follow the bone you have selected. You can make two or more bones control a vertex by giving that vertex a weight from multiple bones.